# Check current user in SharePoint group in InfoPath

Tags: infopath

Is it possible to check current user in SharePoint group in InfoPath form?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Hide sections of InfoPath form based on Group membership](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/84363/how-to-hide-sections-of-infopath-form-based-on-group-membership)

Comment: For 2010 or 2013?

Comment: For 2013 InfoPath