# About Infopath 2010

Tags: infopath

I am working on Infopath 2010 form. The form consists of two parts, one part is for requester and another for manager use.

Requester: When the requester filling the form, the manager part form should be invisible for him.

how to approach this one in Infopath 2010 whether without coding is possible to make invisible or coding is required.

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/84363/how-to-hide-sections-of-infopath-form-based-on-group-membership

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use views, or sections, but I find views are easier. You can show and hide views/sections based on permission, or field values. So when a requester is filling out the form, field Status might be blank, or default to New. After they save, a small WF can notify the Manager and then set the Status to Review, and then the view/section can be shown for the manager.